# Python Change Dict Values with Key-Chain

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Good day,

I am trying to edit a Dict:
e.g:
`a = {"key0" : [{"key01":1}], "key1" : 2}`

I want to change the value from key01, like:
`a["key0"][0][key01] = 2`

But I dont know, how deep the Dict is, so I managed to put the ["key0"][0][key01] - Key-Chain in a List.
But I can't find any pointer notation or dict addressing methode, that would help.

Thanks for your help.
Best Regards
Alex

I tried addressing a with references, but I cant change a through them.

Comment: There are third-party libraries that provide functions that do the necessary recursion or iteration needed to dig into nested data structures as they are identified. This isn't something the language itself provides any support for directly.

Comment: You should not have a structure for which you _"dont know, how deep the Dict is"_, as you have put it. This dict is terrible. Why is it like that and why don't you know what is in it?

Answer (score 0):

quite broad, but if there will be only one occurrence of that key within the collections, then a through recursive find and update should do the job,

something like this (test it)

```
def recursive_update(collection_, key, new_val):
    if isinstance(collection_, dict):
        if key in collection_:
            collection_[key] = new_val
            return
        for k, v in collection_.items():
            recursive_update(v, key, new_val)

    if isinstance(collection_, list):
        for v in collection_:
            recursive_update(v, key, new_val) 


a = {"key0": [{"key01": 1}], "key1": 2}
recursive_update(a, "key01", 2)
```

However, if you know the pattern of the data, then a better find&replace can be written.

Comment: Thank you, I would prefer a solution which works also on recurring keys.
The Structure of the Data is known as far, that the value is either a string/int or a list of dicts following the same rule.

Comment: Hmm, then removing the return statement from this solution should replace values for multiple key occurrences